Java 8 comparator manage null values
I m building a Java 8 application. So I have the following method to return the double value from a list of Object in base of max(date). So this is the method:
public static Double getUltimoPrezzo(List<ArticoliPerFornitore> lista)
{
    try
    {
        ArticoliPerFornitore lastContact = Collections.max(
            lista,
            Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getDataUltimoAcquisto())
        );
        return lastContact.getPrezzoUltimoAcquisto();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.logStackTrace(e);
    }
    return null;
}

This method works but in case of list with one element with "getPrezzoUltimoAcquisto" = null, the method return null. Is possible exclude null values?

It would help if you would post a [mre].

Just don't return null at the end? What do you want to return when getPrezzoUltimoAcquisto is null? It's up to you.

You can use Comparatir.nullsFirst(). Or Comparatir.nullsLast().

How can I use Comparator.nullsFirst()?

Something like var latest = lista.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(ArticoliPerFornitore::getDataUltimoAcquisto))); 

If you want to guard against the date being null, then var latest = list.stream().filter(f ->Objects.nonNull(f.getDataUltimoAcquisto())).collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(ArticoliPerFornitore::getDate)));

Your method returns null?? From reading the code I would expect it to throw a NullPointerException if  some dataUltimoAcquisto is null.

ArticoliPerFornitore lastContact = Collections.max( lista, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getDataUltimoAcquisto())) );.If all items in your list have null dataUltimoAcquisto, it will give you the first such item from the list (I believe). If you like method references (like I do), the inner comparator may be written as Comparator.comparing(ArticoliPerFornitore::getDataUltimoAcquisto).

What do you want as a result if there is a null (or several) in the list ?

This may do it. But you may need to change some things to get it to work with your case.
The first is a working example with a null.  Note that maxBy returns an optional.  I chose to throw an exception if the list is empty.

 List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(
         List.of(1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 10., 11., 2., 3., 1.));
 list.add(null);
 double v = list.stream().filter(i -> i != null)
         .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
         .orElseThrow(()->new IllegalArgumentException("List is empty"));
 System.out.println(v);

prints
11.0

Here is yours modified.


public static Double getUltimoPrezzo(List<ArticoliPerFornitore> lista) {
    ArticoliPerFornitore lastContact = lista.stream()
                .filter(c -> c.getDataUltimoAcquisto() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator
                        .comparing(c -> c.getDataUltimoAcquisto())))
                .orElseThrow(()->new IllegalArgumentException("List is empty"));
}


Double.MIN_VALUE doesn't do what you think it does.

Yes, but it's not a good value to return as a default.  It's the smallest positive nonzero double.  Use 0, -Double.MAX_VALUE, or Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY.

@LouisWasserman  I changed it to throw an exception.  Thanks for the comment!

@WJS your code seems good but can I get the last element of the list if every item have getDataUltimoAcquisto() = null?

Sure.  Use .orElseGet with the last element.

You can avoid applying the .filter(i -> i != null) operation by changing the comparator in  .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))). Comparator.nullsFirst (or nullsLast) is null friendly.

@prasad_ but why should avoiding .filter(i -> i != null) be a goal? Your alternative is not simpler.
